# Efficiently counting the rolling number of consecutive unique values

Tags: r, algorithm

Given

```
author = c("A","B","A","B","C","D","C")
```

I would like the output to be any one of:

```
[1] 1 2 2 2 3 4 2
```

Or

```
[1] 1 2 1 2 3 4 1
```

Or

```
[1] 2 4 1
```

The first one gives the rolling number of unique letters, the second is a counter which resets to 1 whenever a letter is repeated, the last one counts the lengths of unique runs (i.e. `A-B` is `2`, `A-D` is `4`, `B` is `1`).

The first implementation is the best because it will never miss a streak.

Currently I have the third implementation:

```
author = c("A","B","A","B","C","D","C")
n = length(author)
streak = rep(0,floor(n/2))
i = 1; counter = 1
while (i <= n)
{
  p = duplicated(author[i:(i+35)])
  i_new = i + Position(function(x) x==TRUE, p) - 1
  streak[counter] = i_new - i
  i = i_new
  counter = counter + 1
}
streak
```

This counts the number of non-duplicated items until the first duplicate and changes the index position to the element that breaks the consecutive run of non-duplicates. I've determined this to be faster than keeping track of the elements I've seen and checking whether each new element is a duplicate.

The output of this is `2 4 0` (because `i+35` is out of bounds for the given `author`), and that's okay because the last element doesn't really matter that much. We can also assume there is not streak longer than 35.

My main issue is that this takes a long time to run because the real `author` vector is huge.

How can I perform this task more efficiently?

---

---

Edit: Following @Dikran's answer, the updated code is:

```
author = c("A","B","A","B","C","D","C")
authorList = unique(author)
authorVals = 1:length(authorList)
authorHash = setNames(authorVals, authorList) # in R internally is a hash table
authorTabl = rep(0, length(authorVals))
author = as.integer(revalue(author, authorHash))
n = length(author)
streak = rep(0,floor(n/2))
index = rep(0,floor(n/2))
i = 1; counter = 1; first = 1; last = 1
for (i in 1:n)
{
  authorTabl[author[last]] = authorTabl[author[last]] + 1
  while (authorTabl[author[last]] == 2)
  {
    authorTabl[author[first]] = authorTabl[author[first]] - 1
    first = first + 1
  }
  last = last + 1
  streak[counter] = last - first
  counter = counter + 1
}
streak
```

Which is fast, and gives:

```
[1] 1 2 2 2 3 4 2
```

Comment: how many distinct values are there in the author set?

Comment: @DikranMarsupial There are 4,000 unique authors, however 40 of them make up 95% of the set. There are 22M entries in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to have a map data structure with one entry for each author that records the number of times it is seen in the window.  If the map is implemented using a [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with one list per author then the average lookup time will be O(1) complexity (with only 4000 authors the memory overhead for this isn't too problematic for modern computers).  Most modern programming languages, like C++, Java or Python, will have a library implementation of a Hash-based map, so you shouldn't need to code it from scratch.

Create variables, "first" and "last", which give the indices of first and last entries in the current run of unique authors.  Both are initialised to the first element of the sequence.  Increment the author count in the map for the author referenced by "first".

At each step increment "last" and increment the author count for the the indexed author.  If it has been incremented to one, then it must be a new unique entry in the run.  If it isn't then we have a duplicate in the run somewhere, so start decrementing the author count corresponding to "first" and then increment "first".  If the author count is decremented to zero, that isn't the author with a duplicate in the current run, so we have to continue.  If it is decremented to one, you have just found the previous entry that has been duplicated, so the rest of the run should now be unique (as looking at the next element of the sequence can only introduce one duplicate).

At each stage, the difference between "last" and "first" gives you the length of the run of unique entries in the sequence that ends at "last".

The computational complexity of this algorithm is linear in the number of elements of the sequence, and constant in the number of authors (because hash-table look-up is O(1)).  I think it will be difficult to do much better than linear time!

I hope I have understood the question correctly, but that would be my approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been staring at this for about 15 minutes and I think I finally understand your suggestion. I think it should work, but the one concern I have is whether you think it would it be feasible to look-up a 4,000 long table 22M times? And is there a way to optimise the look-up when I know the frequency of the unique authors in the set?

Comment: Yes, hash table look up is very quick, provided the has function distributes the authors evenly.  If you use a library implementation of strings and maps, then it is likely to use an efficient hash function, so you should be O.K.  The trick is to have the same number of lists in the hash table as you the number of authors.  That way on average the author you are looking for will be the only one in that list in the hash table.  This trick is used in the memory manager for some operating systems, so it is *quick*.

Comment: If the hash-table is large enough, the look-up time will be the same regardless of frequency, so it probably won't make much difference.  When speeding up large-scale programming tasks, knowing the right data structure is often vital.

Comment: This method is completely new to me but seems very good. I shall try it now. Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem, quite a fun programming challenge ;o)

Comment: I've added the updated code and it runs 120 times faster than before! I ended up turning the author values to integers (1:4000) and then used simple indexing to look up the values in the `authorTabl` vector.

Comment: @VitaminB16 Excellent!  If converting the author values to integers is acceptable then the array approach is probably going to be appreciably faster than a HashMap

Answer (score 0):

in a loop with length of set do this:
if the input is 'A' then increment a temp value to 1. then after see 'B' in first time increment temp again and so on.